# Filter on custom Django field that has been populated by a function

Tags: django, django-models

I do not know the correct terminology for this, so I hope the title does not lead to confusion.

I have the following model.

```
class Material(models.Model):

    yes = models.IntegerField()
    no =  models.IntegerField()

    def _votes(self):
        return int(self.no + self.yes)

    def _ratio(self):
        v = self.votes
        y = self.yes
        try:
            return float(y)/v
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return float(0)

    ratio = property(_ratio)
    votes = property(_votes)
```

This allows me to query a `Material` item and use each of the fields.

```
Material.objects.all()[0].yes   # returns 5
Material.objects.all()[0].no    # returns 3
Material.objects.all()[0].votes # returns 8
Material.objects.all()[0].ratio # returns 0.625
```

So far so good. I would like to filter on the value of filter. For example, I wanna only select a `Material` instance if ratio is greater than 0.8.

```
Material.objects.filter(ratio__gt=0.8)  # what I'd want to do
```

Doing this however returns and error claiming that `ratio` is not a field.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ratio' into field. Choices are: id, no, yes
```

How could I perform this query? I assume I need to make some changes to my model, so the `ratio` and `votes` are registered as actual fields. How to do so?

Comment: You can use annotations for that.

Comment: You can not filter on properties (or at least not directly), since the database does not know anything about the properties. You can however *encode* your properties into an expression (wel in this case we can, since it is a simple one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Properties and Columns

Properties are defined at the *model* level. Python can handle those properties, and you can do very sophisticated things with it (for example perform a HTTP request). The database is not aware that there are properties, nor have most databases the means to perform very complex functions (typically a database does not perform very complicated tasks itself).

This means that in order to filter, we can do this *after* we retrieved all the values. But this is of course inefficient: it would mean we first load all items into memory, and if the filter is rather restrictive, we will have done a lot of work to only throw away huge chunks of the result.

## Translating properties to `F`-expressions

In case the properties are rather simple, we can however write a database equivalent to it. For example here, your `.vote` property is actually:

```
fvotes = F('yes') + F('no')  # total number of votes
```

Where `F(..)` is an object Django uses to refer to a column.

If for our `ratio` we will always exclude values where there are no `votes` (because the threshold is higher than zero), then we can write our annotation like:

```
fratio = F('yes') / fvotes  # ratio of the votes
```

So now we can *annotate* our database with these extra properties:

```
from django.db.models import F

fvotes = F('yes') + F('no')

Material.objects.annotate(
   votes=fvotes,
   fratio=F('yes') / fvotes
).filter(fratio__gt=0.8)
```

So here we basically have written some query like:

```
SELECT yes, no, yes + no AS votes, yes / (yes + no) AS ratio
FROM material
WHERE ratio > 0.8
```

This query is thus performed at the database level, and this will typically run faster than doing the filtering manually at the Django level. But as said before, it requires some skill to transform Python functions into `F`-expressions. Furthermore some functions *can* not be transformed into expressions. For instance most databases can not access a file system, can not contact a web service, etc. In that case you will have to do the filtering manually.

## Filtering manually (typically less efficient)

In case you have to do the filtering manually (for reasons mentioned above), we can use the `filter(..)` function of Python. Mind that this filter will *not* return a `QuerySet`, hence we can not perform additional `.filter(..)`, `.first()`, `.annotate(..)`, etc. functions on it. We can in that case for example use a lambda expression:

```
filter(lambda x: x.ratio > 0.8, Material.objects.all())
```

So here we load *all* `Material` objects into memory, and let Python manually calculate the `ratio` and perform the checks.